# Check if a running process is 32 or 64 bit

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, process

How can I determine if a specified process is 32 or 64 bit on Windows, Mac and Linux.

On **Linux** and **Mac** I have a pid of the process. I am thinking that if the system itself is 64 bit then the apps should be 64 bit, same with 32 bit. But I heard that 64 bit Linux and Mac can also run 32 bit applications. What can I do to be sure?

On **Windows** I have a Handle to the process. Currently I am using IsWow64Process. Is this correct? (Edit: yes it is correct but needs to be used with [GetNativeSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms724340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see if the OS is 64 bit).

EDIT: For Mac see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983962/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-process-is-64-bit-or-32-bit/27929872) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OS X, `ps`'s flags value includes a bit that indicates 64-bit mode:

```
$ ps -oflags= [PID]
        4004
```

From the ps man page:

```
 flags     The flags associated with the process as in the include file
           <sys/proc.h>:

           P_ADVLOCK           0x00001      Process may hold a POSIX
                                            advisory lock
           P_CONTROLT          0x00002      Has a controlling terminal
           P_LP64              0x00004      Process is LP64
           P_NOCLDSTOP         0x00008      No SIGCHLD when children stop
           [etc...]
```

...so if the flags value's last digit is 4, 5, 6, 7, c, d, e, or f, it's running in LP64 (i.e. 64-bit) mode. In the above example, flags=4004, so the process listed is 64-bit.

Comment: Not completely the answer but it put me on the right track. Additional details in the original question.

Comment: To find all process running in 32 bit mode run `ps aux -oflags | grep '[01238ab]$'`

Answer (score 1):

Use file:

```
file -L /proc/[PID]/exe
```

Comment: I don't know whether MacOS has `/proc/[PID]/exe`. I'm sure Windows doesn't.

Comment: Windows and Mac doesn't. I use libproc for other stuff on Mac.