# Check if app is built in 32 or 64-bit?

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I check whether my app is compiled in 32-bit or 64-bit ?

This is helpful to debug low level code (working with buffers for example).

Comment: Why do you need to know? Properly written code should work fine either way.

Comment: I agree with @dpassage. Though if you need to know check the device model. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/model

Comment: @dpassage Very naive comment. True for simple things, but definitely not, when you want to optimize your code for different CPU architectures.

Comment: That's not quite right because, as I understand it, the iPhone 5S will still run 32-bit apps.

Comment: @dpassage but if you want to optimize for 64-bit, and have a fat binary, where both 32-bit and 64-bit code can launch, you may need to know specifically what the current architecture is to call the correct optimized code.

Comment: There is little need to 'optimize' for 64-bit processors in most cases, especially in a dynamically-typed object-oriented language like Objective-C where inlining is impossible.  The only reason you'd ever need a check like this is for serious math (which would be better suited to Accelerate, or NEON), or defining architecture-agnostic types, which are fairly well represented in the STLs of most languages.

Comment: Need more explanation about your issue to help you out..

Comment: @dpassage Not really, On iOS 7.0.x Core face detection does not work if a 32bit app is run on a 64bit device (5s). It is a bug in iOS.

Answer (score 19):

A compile time check would involve `#ifdef`'ing for `__LP64__`, which is ARM's data type size standard.  A runtime solution would involve checking the size of pointers, like so:

```
if (sizeof(void*) == 4) {
    // Executing in a 32-bit environment
} else if (sizeof(void*) == 8) {
   // Executing in a 64-bit environment
}
```

Thankfully, pointer sizes are the one thing that the different standards for compiling 64-bit code seem to agree on.

Comment: Just FYI, both the `__LP64__` and `sizeof()` solutions are compile-time. Evaluating sizeof is part of the compile process, and not a function.  The compiler basically replaces sizeof(type) with the size of that type on the system you're compiling for.  Ideally, the #ifdef and if/else will end up compiling identically because the compiler will see that 8 is always == 8 and optimize out the 8 == 4 branch.

Comment: Technically, you're correct (but your argument is founded on the assumption of the optimizing compiler).  Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7984249/945847) would fit a more rigorous definition of "runtime check".

Answer (score 16):

```
#ifdef __LP64__
    NSLog(@"64-bit\t");
#else
    NSLog(@"32-bit\t");
#endif
```

Comment: This compile time. The question is for runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the size of a pointer. I think on 32bit it is 4bytes and on 64 it should be 8.

```
if( sizeof(void*) == 4 ) then 32bit else 64bit
```

Comment: int remains 4 bytes in 64 bit.

Comment: oh that is sad, one could try sizeof(void)

Comment: You should try this with NSInteger. "When building 32-bit applications, NSInteger is a 32-bit integer. A 64-bit application treats NSInteger as a 64-bit integer."

Comment: @LeoNatan Finally, Can i consider sizeof(void*) to be the best option of all ?